# SQL query with list of random ids and associated integers

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have data as below:

```
BinaryName                     Licens_details
-------------------------------------------------------


usr/sbin/if_up                    BSD-2C:63, BSD-2C:1576, BSD-3C:4, BSD-3C:214, 
                                  BSD-3C:241, BSD-3C:248, BSD-3C:259, BSD-4C:62,
                                  BSD-4C:137, BSD-4C:154, BSD-4C:164, BSD-V:3, 
                                  NOTE:4, NOTE:5, NOTE:15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
usr/sbin/random                    BSD-3C:4, BSD-3C:214, BSD-4C:61, BSD-4C:154, 
                                  NOTE:4, NOTE:5, NOTE:15, ZLIB:18, ZLIB:55

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

usr/bin/vcapture-test                BSD-4C:154, NOTE:2, NOTE:4, NOTE:5, NOTE:15

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

License_details data is of pattern :
Each license_id represents full notice text in another table, copright_info id represented by integer is index into other big table with copyright info, author, acknowledgement details etc.
The question is, how do I design query to get both license id, and copyright id since they are very random, not serial.

One way is to manually see every id and design a query for every row of data.
But this is quite takes more effort as we more than 300 pages of data.

Another way is to have that data in excel, and parse by perl script.
The perl script becomes a table column. I mean every row of table should execute a perl script to get list of license ids, and copyright ids.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I dont think we have any datatype to store list of ids as follows. -- BSD-3C:4, BSD-3C:214, BSD-4C:61, BSD-4C:154, 
                                  NOTE:4, NOTE:5, NOTE:15, ZLIB:18, ZLIB:55 - my thinking is can we have a perl script in table column and execute it when i need to execute a table query?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, BSD-2C:63 represents an id of BSD-2C on one table and an id of 63 on the copyright info table? Is that the case?

Comment: Au contraire.  SQL is built on a "data type" to store lists of things.  It is called a table.

Comment: @Kickstart - you are right, but if you see the above data 3 samples I have given, for each binary name, this ids are random. How can store that data in a column, because there are one or more? Can i store as array of strings?

Comment: You split them off into a different table to store them, with many rows for each "BinaryName", one for each BinaryName / Licens_details combination. Storing arrays / comma separated lists of values in a field in MySQL makes it difficult and slow to join to related info.